# Why can't I have a main loop

Tags: screeps

I've always written programs such that I have a main loop:

```
initialiseStuff();
while(1){
    doRepetitiveStuff();
}
```

But it seems that screeps will give me a "console not responding" error if I attempt this.

Why does it do this? I'm guessing that the game waits for the end of your script before doing something perhaps?

How can I achieve what I want (do some methods, set variables, only once) when the entire main is repeated every tick?

Comment: try lazy-loading whatever "setup" you need; or as @artch mentioned, don't care about it at all, and have a different design. at the very least, you will learn a new paradigm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I achieve what I want (do some methods, set variables, only once) when the entire main is repeated every tick?

Basically, you can't execute something only once. The game engine runs that infinite loop on its own, you can't get out of it.

It is important to understand, that Screeps is a multiplayer online game. Your and other players' scripts are being executed server-side. That means you could simply break the game engine process with such infinite loops as in your example.

Also, due to distributed and scalable server architecture, your script could run on different machines along different game ticks. Thus, it doesn't make any sense to make an initial script setup, as it won't be shared between multiple separated machines' runtime environment.

See more details on how the game loop works in this article: [Understanding game loop, time and ticks](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/203032752-Understanding-game-loop-time-and-ticks).

Answer (score 0):

Your script never terminates (in this case a while loop that never terminates). Note that the script is running in a separate process that is timed.

After a certain time, at least if the script isn't finished, the simulator can mark the ai as not working properly and can choose what to do with it. For example giving a notice to the user that the script is not responding, or in competition simply shutting down the ai.

The best thing you can do is avoid hard calculations, or spread them over separate ticks while keeping the result in memory. Please note that the simulator doesn't change any game state while its executing your bot (it only does that when all bots have executed their code).

Any troubles with that part?

Comment: The screeps api can be found here http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/203084991-API-Reference

Here a quick example for a counter that ticks 1 higher every time it gets executed:

`if (Memory.ticks === undefined) Memory.ticks = 0;
Memory.ticks++;`